# How to Create a Form Dynamically Via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My sites Aweber registration forms are getting a lot of spam. I was told to create the forms dynamically via javascript after page has rendered or via clicking button. How would I create and render a form via javascript?

Comment: what do you mean by creating a form dynamically?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted so much or closed.  Dynamic form generation via javascript means building the DOM rather than serving it via HTML.

Comment: He means creating a form after the page has been rendered. Why was this closed?

Comment: I wonder, is there a library for this, similar to the (PHP) Drupal Form API?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

some thing as follows ::

Add this After the body tag

This is a rough sketch, you will need to modify it according to your needs.

```
<script>
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
i.setAttribute('type',"text");
i.setAttribute('name',"username");

var s = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
s.setAttribute('type',"submit");
s.setAttribute('value',"Submit");

f.appendChild(i);
f.appendChild(s);

//and some more input elements here
//and dont forget to add a submit button

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);

</script>
```

Comment: How would you add a button (along side submit) to remove the respective form?

Comment: For some reason, the submit button for this code does not work in IE Edge, or previous versions of IE. Puzzled as to why