# form not created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have written a jQuery plugin as a form element that I want to reuse throughout mysite.

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.create = function() {
        var form = '<div id="form" class="container">';
        form += '<div>User Login</div>';
        form += '<form action="/create" method="post">';
        form += '<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">';
        form += '<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">';
        form += '<button type="submit">Login</button>';
        form += '</form>';
        form += '</div>';
        return this.append(form);
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

In HTML view,

```
<div id="#newForm"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#newForm").create(); 
});
</script>
```

However, the form does not get rendered onto `#newForm`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964927/how-to-create-a-form-dynamically-via-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an `#` in the id of the target div, remove the prefixed `#` and it should be fine

```
<div id="newForm"></div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/33vG7/)

Comment: oh awesome! thanks for catching that!